# Getting "unknown encoding name" error during Selenium startup on Windows with Ruby

Tags: ruby, windows, selenium

I'm getting the error:

> lib/ruby/1.9.1/win32/registry.rb:172:in `find': unknown encoding name - CP0 (ArgumentError)

when starting up Selenium.  I'm running on Windows 7 with Helios eclipse.  Here's the ruby code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
```

I saw the post about eMacs headers, but couldn't see how that applied in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Try to enter in a console before starting your script: 
chcp 1256

Comment: Not sure what you meant by "enter in a console", but I just tried executing those three lines of Ruby code from IRB started up from a command window.  I got "Firefox has stopped working" popup with the following error details:


    Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
    Application Name: firefox.exe
    Application Version: 7.0.1.4288
    Application Timestamp: 4e83b93a
    Fault Module Name: MOZCRT19.dll
    Fault Module Version: 8.0.0.0
    Fault Module Timestamp: 4e839918
    Exception Code: c0000005
    Exception Offset: 000083b8
    OS Version: 6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.4
    Locale ID: 1033

Comment: Your initial error related with wrong code page. 'chcp' is a command for cmd.exe (aka command interpreter). What's happening if you enter 'chcp 1256' command and then ruby your_script.rb?